# Problem building ios framework with subspec for cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-frameworks, podspec, subspec

This is my SDK's podspec:

```
#
#  Be sure to run `pod spec lint Core.podspec' to ensure this is a
#  valid spec and to remove all comments including this before submitting the spec.
#
#  To learn more about Podspec attributes see http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html
#  To see working Podspecs in the CocoaPods repo see https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "TiendeoCore"
  s.version          = "0.1.10"
  s.summary          = "Tiendeo Core"
  s.homepage         = "https://www.tiendeo.com"
  s.license          = 'Custom'
  s.author           = { "Tiendeo" => "info@tiendeo.com" }
  s.platform         = :ios, '10.0'

  #REMOTE 
s.source = { "http" => "https://tiendeo.jfrog.io/tiendeo/pods/TiendeoCore/TiendeoCore-0.1.10.zip" }

  #LOCAL#   s.source = { :git => "https://gitlab.tiendeo.com/ios/core-ios.git", :tag => s.version }
  s.dependency "Governor", "~> 0.2.5"
  s.dependency "AlamofireObjectMapper", "~> 5.2"
  s.dependency "Alamofire", "~> 4.8"
  s.dependency "RealmSwift", "~> 3.11.1"
  s.dependency "RxSwift", "~> 4.2.0"
  s.default_subspec = 'Lite'

  s.subspec 'Lite' do |lite|
    lite.name = "Lite"
    #REMOTE 
lite.framework = "TiendeoCore"
    #REMOTE 
lite.vendored_frameworks = 'TiendeoCore.framework'
     #LOCAL#     lite.source_files     = ["Source/**/*.swift", "Source/Core.h"]
     #LOCAL#     lite.public_header_files = ["Source/Core.h"]
     #LOCAL#     lite.resource_bundles = {
     #LOCAL#       'TiendeoCore' => ['Source/**/*.{xib,png,jpg,json,xcdatamodeld,xcdatamodel,xcassets,ttf,lproj}']
     #LOCAL#     }
  end

  s.subspec 'Full' do |full|
    full.name = "Full"
    #REMOTE 
full.framework = "TiendeoCore"
    #REMOTE 
full.vendored_frameworks = 'TiendeoCore.framework'

    #LOCAL#     full.source_files     = ["Source/**/*.swift", "Source/Core.h"]
    #LOCAL#     full.public_header_files = ["Source/Core.h"]
    #LOCAL#     full.resource_bundles = {
    #LOCAL#       'TiendeoCore' => ['Source/**/*.{xib,png,jpg,json,xcdatamodeld,xcdatamodel,xcassets,ttf,lproj}']
    #LOCAL#     }
    full.xcconfig = {
         'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS' => '$(inherited) -DFULLTIENDEOCORE'
    }
    full.dependency "TiendeoAuth", "~> 0.0.6"
    full.dependency "FacebookCore", '~> 0.4.0'
  end


end
```

I'm building a **TiendeoCore.framework** for upload it to cocoapods with the command (I have an script that build .framework and copy the simulator's architectures, I'm showing the main commands of the script):

```
xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE_PATH}" -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS='arm64 armv7' BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode clean build

xcodebuild -workspace "${WORKSPACE_PATH}" -scheme "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS='i386 x86_64' BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" ENABLE_BITCODE=YES OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode clean build
```

The upload of the framework to cocoapods finish successfully, but when I install the version on my project (build and run ok), the app throws this error on start:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Bolts.framework/Bolts
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/43993CDF-61A7-405F-BA37-6FAD4B8B5FFF/ViewerPro-Demo.app/Frameworks/TiendeoCore.framework/TiendeoCore
  Reason: image not found
```

My podspec has two subspec (**lite** and **full**), I'm installing the **lite** version by default but at runtime **TiendeoCore.framworks** throws that needs a dependency of **full** **subspec**, Facebook in this case.

In my code, I have a preprocessing flag called **FULLTIENDEOCORE** to enclose source code that use dependencies of **full** version:

```
#if FULLTIENDEOCORE
import TiendeoAuth
#endif
```

So if the Flag is declared in **OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS** then the code will be executed (this flag is added on the podspec in the **full** subspec).

I don't know what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved this issue??? This is exact problem our team has run into. Maybe you can share some insights? Because I can't even successfully upload Pod, which have subspecs as are compiled vendored frameworks

Comment: Hi Viktor! We didn't solve this issue, we are going to create two separate targets and generate two different .framework. And we are going to specify different sources for every subspec. We think that you can't have one .framework for two subspec with different dependencies. So we are going to have two.

Comment: We have generated two different frameworks, but our main framework cannot reference code from another optional framework.. We use #if canImport() tag and it always fails... Please provide example, of how can we access code from optional framework in the main framework???
Can we chat in some private chat? Here is my linkedIn:
https://www.linkedin.com/in/viktor-vostrikov-245975a7/

Answer (score 0):

Subspecs are designed to be merged so that consumers can choose a subset of the available subspecs.  By using the same name for both `vendored_frameworks`, it is likely that the wrong one is getting referenced.

If that doesn't help you may want to investigate the [current open subspec issues](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20subspecs).

Comment: Can you share an example of successfully including vendored frameworks as a subspecs?

Comment: Firebase does it by wrapping the vendored_framework in another podspec that is a dependency of the subspec - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.17.0/Firebase.podspec.json

Comment: I did not found vendored_framework in that example.. Here is my attempt:


mainFramework.subspec 'additionalFramework' do |additionalFramework|
additionalFramework.name = "additionalFramework"
additionalFramework.vendored_frameworks = "additionalFramework.framework"
end


Now I am referencing a fully compiled framework which is optional. I could also add CocoaPods dependencies to that  'additionalFramework' and also include static framework directly(I found your post in stackOverflow about it)

**mainFramework.static_framework = true**

Am I correct or absolutely wrong?